# Manipulating Android build.prop file

Tags: android, build, android-emulator, system

I am trying to manipulate the Android API level 17 **build.prop** file and make some changes on device's MODEL, ID, FINGERPRINT values and more. I manipulated the **system.img** file and it works perfectly when the number of characters in the file still the same after the change, but when I add more or less it crash.

```
Quiestion: Is there a way that the system.img file number of characters
 is checked? How can I successfully manipulate build.prop file?
```

Thank you.

Comment: How do you modify the system.img file? do you un-yaffs?

Comment: Nope, I'm opening the file with a Hex Editor.

Comment: It is obvious that it will crash... If you add more characters, it will over-write other important stuff. If you add less than it will have some data that has no meaning, so it'll crash  again.. The proper way to edit is too `un-yaffs` it.. The `system.img` is a yaffs2 file system. So you need a program that can un-yaffs2 it and then yaffs2 it. As far as I know there are a lot for linux, but I don't know if there is anything for windows.

Comment: For windows check this out https://code.google.com/p/yaffey/

Answer (score 8):

This is 3 yrs old question but still answering for ppl checking later - 
Not sure why you can't pull build.prop from target edit in host and push back to target

```
adb root
adb remount
adb pull /system/build.prop
<Edit in host>
adb push build.prop /system/
adb shell sync
adb reboot
```